# How to properly require stripe library to avoid Error 500 on stripe Webhook

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm trying to use stripe Webhooks but struggling a little bit.
I have an endpoint file ipn.php at the root of my website.
I also have installed stripe source code.

Though stripe interface, I send a test Webhook to this endpoint.

This code works well :

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$input = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event = json_decode($input);

http_response_code(200);

if($event->type == "charge.succeeded") {
   echo $event->data->object->id;
}

?>
```

When I test
but as soon as I add those two lines :

```
require_once('stripe/lib/Stripe.php');
Stripe::setApiKey("whsec_myAPIKeyHere");
```

I've got this response :

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Stripe' not found in /home/ftpHostName/www/myWebsiteWithout.com/ipn.php:11
Stack trace:

## 0 {main}

thrown in **/home/ftpHostName/www/myWebsiteWithout.com/ipn.php:11** on line **11**

I havent done any php before, and I think the problem comes from the   require_once('stripe/lib/Stripe.php');

Stripe documentation says to use Composer (which I don't know how to use) or download the source code (that's what I did). https://stripe.com/docs/libraries#php

Also, in the error, I don't understand the url I get : why the FTP hostname appears here ?

Comment: Whats the path of the stripe folder?

Comment: Hello the stripe folder is at the root of my website like my ipn.php file. I also tried this  path : require_once('./stripe/lib/Stripe.php'); but have the same issue,

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: Include with `init.php` and not `Stripe.php` like you are doing above, this is described in their docs, https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#manual-installation

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because its not finding the class `Stripe`.

This is most likely happening because the path of the file containing the class - `stripe/lib/Stripe.php` is not correct.

Without knowing where the stripe directory is, its hard to say exactly what path you need to put, but if you have the stripe directory in the same path as the `ipn.php` like:

```
ipn.php
stripe/
stripe/lib/
stripe/lib/Stripe.php
```

Then you can just do:

```
require_once (__DIR__ . '/stripe/lib/Stripe.php');
```

So your file will look something like this:

```
<?php
require_once (__DIR__ . '/stripe/lib/Stripe.php');
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Stripe::setApiKey("whsec_myAPIKeyHere");

$input = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event = json_decode($input);

http_response_code(200);

if($event->type == "charge.succeeded") {
   echo $event->data->object->id;
}

?>
```

Where `__DIR__` returns the current directory of the working file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately I have the same error.

Comment: Can you go into your `Stripe.php` file and at the top of the page (after the <?php tag) type `echo __DIR__; die();` and then visit the `Stripe.php` file in your browser.

Comment: Actually, can you confirm you are using `require_once (__DIR__ . '/stripe/lib/Stripe.php');` at the top of the page (after the <?php tag). Not half way down

Comment: /home/ftpHostName/www/myWebsiteWithout.com/stripe/lib

Comment: See my message about the position of the require statement. I have also updated my answer to show an example

Comment: Ok finallly I found the solution : the Stripe class is inside a namespace Stripe. So I just did this \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("whsec_myAPIKeyHere");
I don't understand why the Stripe documentation is not correct...
Thank you for your help I opened the Stripe.php thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

You should include the `init.php` that comes with Stripe's PHP SDK, rather than trying to directly load `Stripe.php`, e.g. `require_once (__DIR__ . '/stripe-php/init.php')`

Stripe describes this [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#manual-installation).